# Use custom firefox browser version capability for geckodriver

Tags: selenium, geckodriver, selenoid

I build selenoid docker images for firefox myself and have them configured in the `browsers.json` as follows:

```
 "firefox": {
    "default": "66.0",
    "versions": {
      "beta": {
        "image": "my/path/to/firefox:beta",
        "port": "4444"
      },
      "66.0": {
        "image": "selenoid/vnc:firefox_66.0",
        "port": "4444"
      }
    }
  }
```

Sending the `version=beta` capability causes the webdriver to throw

`selenium.WebDriverException: Requested environment is not available`

In the logs I found

```
2019/04/03 08:17:29 [3] [PROXY_TO] [90ab834d22aa3bbe2731eeb550497eec7ef9fb11c1e7f4609d617cf6a25124e7] [http://172.17.0.4:4444]
2019/04/03 08:17:29 [3] [SESSION_ATTEMPTED] [http://172.17.0.4:4444] [1]
2019/04/03 08:17:29 [3] [SESSION_ATTEMPTED] [http://172.17.0.4:4444/wd/hub] [2]
2019/04/03 08:17:29 [3] [SESSION_FAILED] [http://172.17.0.4:4444/wd/hub] [400 Bad Request]
```

Since the exact same thing works for chrome and it also works if I set `"default": "beta"` in the `browsers.json` and do not set the `version` capability, I assume this happens because geckodrivers matches the version from the capabilites against the actual browser version. (as presumed [here](https://github.com/aerokube/ggr/issues/207)).

I have several ideas how to work around this, but do not know how to technically implement these:

- Prevent Selenoid from passing the `version` capability to the selenium driver (geckodriver in this case)
- Prevent geckodriver from checking `version` capability and browser version
- Add another flag to selenoid to get the docker image from `browsers.json` such as `browser_version` instead of `version`
- Add another fake browser to `browsers.json` and set the beta to default, then just set the `browserName` capability. The problem here is, selenoid checks for the browser names and if it does not match `chrome`, `firefox` or `opera` the selenoid container cannot be started. E.g.:

`browserName=firefox-beta`

```
 "firefox-beta": {
    "default": "beta",
    "versions": {
      "beta": {
        "image": "my/path/to/firefox:beta",
        "port": "4444"
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help or further information will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Selenoid supports `browserVersion` capability, too.

Comment: @vania-pooh Setting `browserVersion=beta` still results in geckodriver throwing an exception. I think you can not set another value as a version than the browsers actual version, which does not seem to work for beta versions.

Answer (score 0):

For w3c compliant browsers (as of today, only non-Chrome), they require the browser version to be in the `browserVersion` capability instead of `version`. I see you tried `browser_version`, but did you try `browserVersion`?

https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#capabilities

Comment: The problem is not that `version` is not recognized by the geckodriver but rather that it **is recognized**. I have to set the `version=beta` capability in order for selenoid to use the right docker image. Selenoid then passes all my capabilities to the webdriver and this is the problem. The geckodriver tries to match the browser version set in the capabilities with the one of the installed browser. And as I pass the version `beta` and the browser does not have the version `beta` but something like `67.0.123` the webdriver throws an exception.